# MySQL returns NULL instead of actual value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm writing a MySQL stored procedure that will select a row, replace some column values, and then update the row.  My problem is the SELECT statement is not fetching all values.  That is, columns that have values in the CLI, show up as NULL in my stored proc.  Here is my table definition:

```
Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
id              | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
mac             | varchar(32) | YES  | UNI | NULL              
ip              | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL              
type            | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL              
location_id     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              
name            | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL
manufacturer    | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL              
model           | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL              
serial_number   | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL              
owner           | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              
assigned_to     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              
contact         | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              
admin           | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              
status          | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              
authorized      | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 0                 
authorized_by   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              
date_authorized | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL              
date_first_seen | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL              
date_last_seen  | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL              
impact          | smallint(6) | YES  |     | NULL              
os_id           | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              
updated_at      | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
org_unit_id     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              
is_virtual      | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 0                 
notes           | text        | YES  |     | NULL
```

Here is part of my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `updatehw`(mac varchar(32), ipaddr varchar(16), typ varchar(16),
                            loc int, name varchar(64), maker varchar(64),
                            model varchar(64), ser_no varchar(64), owner int,
                            assignee int, contact int, admin int, status int,
                            authorized tinyint, authorizer int, auth_date datetime,
                            impact smallint, os_id int, org int, virtual tinyint,
                            seen tinyint, notes text, 
                OUT error int, OUT error_text varchar(64))
   MODIFIES SQL DATA
proc_label: BEGIN
   Declare rc INT;
   Declare hw_mac varchar(32);
   Declare hw_ip varchar(16);
   Declare hw_type varchar(16);
   Declare hw_location_id INT;
   Declare hw_name varchar(64);
   Declare hw_manufacturer varchar(64);
   Declare hw_model varchar(64);
   Declare hw_serial_number varchar(64);
   Declare hw_owner INT;
   Declare hw_assigned_to INT;
   Declare hw_contact INT;
   Declare hw_admin INT;
   Declare hw_status INT;
   Declare hw_authorized tinyint;
   Declare hw_authorized_by INT;
   Declare hw_date_authorized, l_date_authorized DATETIME;
   Declare hw_date_first_seen DATETIME;
   Declare hw_date_last_seen DATETIME;
   Declare hw_impact smallint;
   Declare hw_os_id INT;
   Declare hw_updated_at timestamp;
   Declare hw_org_unit_id INT;
   Declare hw_is_virtual tinyint;
   Declare hw_notes text;

   Declare Exit Handler for SQLEXCEPTION
   BEGIN
      ROLLBACK;
      Set error = -99;
      Set error_text = 'SQL Exception detected';
   End;

   Set error = 0;
   Set error_text = NULL;
   insert into log (msg) values ("updateHW starting"); -- DEBUG

   Start Transaction;
   -- See if the row exists and lock it
   insert into log (msg) values (concat_ws('=','ipaddr',ipaddr)); -- DEBUG
   Select mac, ip, type, location_id, name, manufacturer,
          model, serial_number, owner, assigned_to, contact,
          admin, status, authorized, authorized_by,
          date_authorized, date_first_seen, date_last_seen,
          impact, os_id, org_unit_id, is_virtual, notes
     into hw_mac, hw_ip, hw_type, hw_location_id, hw_name, hw_manufacturer,
          hw_model, hw_serial_number, hw_owner, hw_assigned_to, hw_contact,
          hw_admin, hw_status, hw_authorized, hw_authorized_by,
          hw_date_authorized, hw_date_first_seen, hw_date_last_seen,
          hw_impact, hw_os_id, hw_org_unit_id, hw_is_virtual, hw_notes
     from hardware where ip=ipaddr
     lock in share mode;
   insert into log (msg) values (concat_ws(' ',"hw_owner after select is",hw_owner)); -- DEBUG
   insert into log (msg) values (concat_ws(' ',"hw_authorized_by after select is",hw_authorized_by)); -- DEBUG
   insert into log (msg) values (concat_ws(' ',"hw_authorized after select is",hex(hw_authorized))); -- DEBUG
   insert into log (msg) values (concat_ws(' ',"hw_is_virtual after select is",hex(hw_is_virtual))); -- DEBUG
   Select found_rows() into rc;
   If rc = 0 THEN
      set error = -11;
      set error_text = 'Entry not found';
      ROLLBACK;
      Leave proc_label;
   End if;
.
.
.
```

The CLI says this is the contents of my row (I'm using placeholder values):

```
             id: 22
            mac: mac
             ip: ip
           type: type2
    location_id: 1
           name: name
   manufacturer: maker
          model: model
  serial_number: serial
          owner: 1
    assigned_to: 1
        contact: 1
          admin: 1
         status: 1
     authorized: 0
  authorized_by: 1
date_authorized: 2013-03-20 08:46:16
date_first_seen: 2013-03-20 09:04:39
 date_last_seen: NULL
         impact: 0
          os_id: NULL
     updated_at: 2013-03-25 09:56:04
    org_unit_id: 1
     is_virtual: 1
          notes: Another note
```

My log shows columns hw_authorized and hw_owner are read as NULL instead of the actual values.

```
| 2013-03-25 13:12:23 |    NULL | updateHW starting                  |
| 2013-03-25 13:12:23 |    NULL | ipaddr=ip                          |
| 2013-03-25 13:12:23 |    NULL | hw_owner after select is           |
| 2013-03-25 13:12:23 |    NULL | hw_authorized_by after select is 1 |
| 2013-03-25 13:12:23 |    NULL | hw_authorized after select is      |
| 2013-03-25 13:12:23 |    NULL | hw_is_virtual after select is 1    |
```

Here is how my table was created:

```
CREATE TABLE hardware (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
mac varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
ip varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
type varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
location_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
name varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
manufacturer varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
model varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
serial_number varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
owner int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
assigned_to int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
contact int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
admin int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
status int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
authorized tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
authorized_by int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
date_authorized datetime DEFAULT NULL,
date_first_seen datetime DEFAULT NULL,
date_last_seen datetime DEFAULT NULL,
impact smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
os_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
org_unit_id int(11) NOT NULL,
is_virtual tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
notes text,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE KEY hardware_idx (mac)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And a sample INSERT:

```
Insert into hardware (mac, ip, type, location_id, name, manufacturer,
                  model, serial_number, owner, assigned_to, contact,
                  admin, status, authorized, authorized_by,
                  date_authorized, date_first_seen,
                  date_last_seen, impact, os_id, org_unit_id, 
                  is_virtual, notes)
          values ('mac','ip','type',1,'name','maker','model','serial',
                  1,1,1,1, 1, 0,
                  1, current_timestamp(), current_timestamp(), current_timestamp(),
                  0, NULL, 1, 1, "Test");
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using MySql 5.1 on CentOS 6.4.

Comment: please provide query to create your table and query to insert some sample data

Comment: Question edited to add the requested info.

Comment: are you able to run that procedure successfully?

Comment: The procedure fails with a "Column cannot be null" error because it tries to update the authorized column with the NULL value it erroneously received from the SELECT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved.  Apparently, there are secret reserved words one cannot use in stored procedures.  I renamed the 'authorized' column to 'is_authorized' and the SELECT statement returned the expected value.

FTR, the column names I had to change were: name, model, status, impact, and os_id.

BTW, I tried using ticks around these column names, but it didn't help.